# File upload automation with selenium webdriver java

Tags: selenium, file-upload, automation

I am trying to automate a file upload a file upload of a pdf document using firefox webdriver and java, but am unable to do so successfully. The html for the "browse" button is as follows:

`< input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-scope" type="file" data-ng-file-select="" accept=".pdf" ng-model="element.value" name="pdfUpload">`

Before:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LYVg.png

I tried uploading using the following:

```
<code>WebElement fileUploadElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='pdfUpload']"));
String filePathToUse = new File("abc.pdf").getAbsolutePath();
fileUploadElement.sendKeys(filePathToUse);
//delay for 3 seconds</code>
```

i've also tried directly using sendKeys with the filepath, and using robots(but this got stuck on the file upload screen after clicking browse since i'm using a mac so no autoit)

after executing the sendKeys statement, "no file selected" becomes "abc.pdf" so webdriver is recognizing the file(i think correct me if i'm wrong). However, when clicking the save and continue button, An alert pops up saying "this field is required" directly beneath the browse button

After:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vdicr.png

If i manually click browse and choose a file, it works fine so the problem is definitely with what i'm doing not the page itself.

I've looked extensively but havn't been able to find someone with the same problem as mine, so any insight would greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance and let me know if more information is needed!

Comment: Not able see the image.

Comment: Is it same control or different controls?

Comment: control to submit? There's a save and continue button which works fine normally but when clicked after automating the upload with sendkeys, gives the error shown in "after"

Comment: Angular file tags are pretty tricky. I could help you(probably) if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: I would appreciate that immensely if you could! Is there any way i can help reproduce said problem?